# Scrollbars on tag synonym page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest

See the issue show up in Chrome.

Probably related to https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/scrollbars-on-user-profile-page

Comment: I'm looking to into this, thanks.

Comment: Is this still happening? I can't repro it in chrome and FF

Comment: @Jin, still happening for me.  Windows 7, latest stable chrome, no extensions.  I tried playing around with different zoom levels and sometimes they go away, but at 100% they're there.

Comment: can you confirm is this is fixed?

Comment: @Jin looks fixed to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this. Will be in the next deployment.